# Call superclass constructor using reflection in Java

Tags: java

My issue is that depending on Lib version (.jar dependency) I use superclass constructor changes from Integer to String for arguments.

```
public class GlowEnchant
    extends EnchantmentWrapper {

public GlowEnchant(int id) {
    super(id);
}

public String getName() {
    return "Glow";
}
```

This is calling older version, but with new EnchantmentWrapper requires String to initiate constructor, and this shows with super that it's a wrong argument. I need to support both old and new Lib (half clients still prefer old one). How can this be done with Reflection (or anything that might be even simpler)?

Comment: If an API (e.g., EnchantmentWrapper) changes in a non-backward-compatible way (e.g., removing the old Integer constructor), then it's expected that the clients also change. You can either overload the constructor in EnchantmentWrapper, thus providing backward compatibility, or change GlowEnchant as well.

Comment: Leave the old API but mark it as @Deprecated.

Comment: @pkpnd 50/50 that use old and new version.

Comment: @PeterLawrey solution is needed to how extend with different superclass "EnchantmentWrapper" when it's constructor input arguments change between versions (EnchantmentWrapper is a part of a .jar library I cannot edit)

Comment: Does the `GlowEnchant` need to be abstract?

Comment: You can compile your implementation against a copy you created which implements both. Then I would use a factory method to call the constructor which will work at runtime.

Comment: @KDM not particularly, I'll change it.

Comment: Ie create your own copy of EnchantmentWrapper to compile against but don't include it in your release. This is just for compilation purposes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey solution should work.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Will try it.

Comment: It's a horrible solution but I suspect it's the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this:

```
public class GlowEnchant extends EnchantmentWrapper {

    public GlowEnchant(int id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public GlowEnchant(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "Glow";
    }

    public static GlowEnchant create(int id) {
        if (hasStringConstructor()) {
            return new GlowEnchant(id + "");
        } else
            return new GlowEnchant(id);
    }

    private static boolean hasStringConstructor() {
        try {
            EnchantmentWrapper.class.getConstructor(String.class);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Use a local copy of EnchantmentWrapper that includes both constructors for compilation.

Comment: `SecurityException` does not imply that there is no such constructor.

Comment: True. Supposed to be only an example :)